How to Display Local Images in Hover Provider in Visual Studio Code Extension?
I'm developing a Visual Studio Code extension and am facing issues displaying local images through a hover provider. The goal is to show an image when hovering over specific file paths in a .aws file recognized by my custom language 'awscript'.
The .aws file contains paths to images that should display when hovered. The paths are relative and the files reside within the workspace. Here is the example line, where I want to be able to hover over the image path:
Look at this beautiful scene: ../images/landscape.png
My hover provider code in TypeScript looks like this:
import * as vscode from 'vscode';
import * as path from 'path';

export function activateHoverProvider(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    const hoverProvider = vscode.languages.registerHoverProvider({ scheme: 'file', language: 'awscript' }, {
        provideHover(document: vscode.TextDocument, position: vscode.Position, token: vscode.CancellationToken) {
            const wordRange = document.getWordRangeAtPosition(position);
            if (!wordRange) {
                return;
            }
    
            const hoveredText = document.getText(wordRange);
            if (isValidImagePath(hoveredText)) {
                const documentPath = path.dirname(document.uri.fsPath);
                const imagePath = path.resolve(documentPath, hoveredText);
                const uri = vscode.Uri.file(imagePath).with({ scheme: 'vscode-resource' });
                const markdown = new vscode.MarkdownString(`![Image Preview](${uri})`);
                markdown.isTrusted = true;

                return new vscode.Hover(markdown);
            }
        }
    });    

    context.subscriptions.push(hoverProvider);
}

function isValidImagePath(filePath: string): boolean {
    return filePath.endsWith('.png') || filePath.endsWith('.jpg') || filePath.endsWith('.gif');
}


The image does not display when I hover over the file path. The URI resolves correctly, and I have verified the path, but all I see is a [broken image icon in the hover tooltip].

I have read that newer APIs might use vscode-webview-resource instead of vscode-resource, but I'm unsure how to apply it in the context of a hover provider that isn't part of a webview.
How can I correctly display local images using a hover provider in a VS Code extension? Is there a specific URI scheme or API method I should use for this purpose?

There are a couple of problems here.
First, are your wordRange and hoverText what you expect - are they the full relative path, so ../images/landscape.png in your example case.
It may depend on what is a word separator in your language.  If . and / are word separators then you probably aren't getting the full path in the wrodRange and thus your image path is not constructed properly.
This works if you are just hovering the landscape of landscape.png:
let hoveredText = document.getText(wordRange) + '.png';

and you also need
markdown.baseUri = vscode.Uri.file(path.join(documentPath, 'images', path.sep));

to set up the relative path to the actual image location.
Demo: I am not using the isValidImagePath() function in the demo so you see it not working where it shouldn't work and working where it should.

So you need to figure out how to get the full image path when hovering over any part of it, and use the baseUri property as well.
If your image paths don't include spaces that would help.  Are they always at the end of the line?  Always preceded by at least one space?  Parse the line to get the path.
Let's say your image paths are always preceded by a space (with no spaces within the path!), then this works to get your full relative path:
const wordRange = document.getWordRangeAtPosition(position, /(?<=\s)([\w\.\\/]*)/);

getWordRangeAtPosition() takes a second regex argument that can specify a custom word to use, in this case, include . and / in what a word is.
Using this code:
const wordRange = document.getWordRangeAtPosition(position, /(?<=\s)([\w\.\\/]*)$/);
                
let hoveredText = document.getText(wordRange);
                        
const markdown = new vscode.MarkdownString(`![Image Preview](${hoveredText})`);

markdown.baseUri = vscode.Uri.file(path.join(documentPath, 'images', path.sep));
                
markdown.isTrusted = true;
        
return new vscode.Hover(markdown, new vscode.Range(position, position));

Here is a demo using this modified getWordRangeAtPosition() definition (again without the isValidImagePath() check):


Is this working for you?
